# Update multiple User Profiles and their properties using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, client-object-model

Is it possible to update multiple user profiles and their properties using CSOM.

I have checked the code for `SetSingleValueproperty()` method, but can't use it for updating multiple properties for different users.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles.PeopleManager.SetMultiValuedProfileProperty` method to set *multi-value* user profile property, for example:

```
using (var ctx = GetSPOContext(webUri,userName,password))
{                                 
     PeopleManager peopleManager = new PeopleManager(ctx);
     var skills = new List<string>() { "SharePoint", "Office 365", "C#", "JavaScript" };
     peopleManager.SetMultiValuedProfileProperty(accountName, "SPS-Skills", skills);
     ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

**Update**

```
var properties = new Dictionary<string,string>();
properties["AboutMe"] = "SharePoint User";
properties["WorkPhone"] = "123-456-7890";

foreach (var p in properties)
{
     peopleManager.SetSingleValueProfileProperty(accountName, p.Key, p.Value);
}
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: This method is for setting multi valued property. What i need is setting multiple properties like ABout Me, WorkPhone,e.t.c . can i loop SetSingleValueproperty() method??

Comment: The answer has been updated